# Curiosity: Why does Firebase not guarantee order of delivery for push messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working with FB Messaging for a little while now and I came across something in the docs that made me curious as to what the reasoning is behind this behaviour:

> There is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent.

It's mentioned a couple of times throughout the documentation but this is one of the places: [MessagingOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingOptions) (under collapseKey)

I've been wondering why Firebase doesn't just send the messages in the order they are received on their servers?

Is this just Google's (Firebase) Cloud Messaging platform works? Does it have to do with performance and efficiency?

Comment: Btw, I'm asking this because I have a chat app that sends notifs. I want to show the last message in the chat (so it would be nice to have push msgs sent in order). I can't use collapseKeys because a user may have more than 4 ongoing chats that have notifications (4 is the max for collapseKeys). The combination of this makes it rather difficult to do what I want to do. Should I implement collapseKeys myself (in the SW) using IndexedDB?

Comment: Message ordering is a classically difficult problem to define and solve.  https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering

Comment: Rly? -1 because I ask a question? :P

Comment: Hey Doug thanks for the link. That's a really good read and useful info :D

Comment: @DougStevenson maybe you could add that as an answer? I could do it but I think the honor should be yours :)